# System.Web.resources.dll não encontrado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Temos um projeto mvc3/dotnet4, que consome servidores DCOM (c++) através de intertops.

Tanto os servidores DCOM (c++) como o projeto mvc3 (c#) eram compilados com visual studio 2013.

Os projetos foram migrados para visual studio 2015.

No windows 2012/8 em diante, tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Mas no windows 2008r2 (x64), quando tenta carregar os sistema feito em mvc3 (c#) dotnet4, ocorre o erro:

> System.Web.resources.dll não encontrado.

Não conseguimos encontrar o problema, já atualizamos os windows 2008r2 com todas as atualizações, foi instalado o visual c redist 2015, reiniciado o servidor, e nada.

Alguém já passou por um problema parecido?

Comment: Experimentou copiar ela manualmente? Tentou instalar com Nuget? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/3.0.20105.1

Comment: Não tentei, mas vou testar.

Comment: Sabes me dizer por que isso aconteceu? Antes de converter os projetos para vs2015 funcionava, inclusive no windows 2008r2, parou de funcionar depois que foram convertidos.

Comment: Não sei, mas é provável que houve algum problema de compatibilidade de versão que você não percebeu. Resolveu?

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou.

Comment: É estranho já que isto instala esta DLL. O problema pode ser outro e este problema é apenas colateral. Mas é difícil a gente ajudar sem ver toda a situação.

Answer (score 2):

@Hains,

Para você descobrir qual a versão e onde ele está procurando esta DLL, sugiro que ative o `Fusion log`, as instruções sobre ativação estão na página de erro, mesmo assim, segue como fazer:

- Crie um diretório em `C:` com o nome `Logs`
- Crie uma chave de registro em `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion\` com o nome `LogPath` e valor `C:\Logs`, outra `ForceLog`com o valor `1` e mais uma `LogFailures` com o valor `1`

Feito isso, reinicie o IIS.

A partir de agora serão exibidos os caminhos e as versões dos arquivos que falharam em serem carregadas.

---

Para ajudar na depuração de erros, veja este artigo publicado na MSDN com mais detalhes sobre como utilizar/interpretar os logs do Fusion.

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/suzcook/debugging-assembly-loading-failures)